# \numcases with \tag

Tags: amsmath, cases

I would like to label some cases with specific tags, and was hoping for something like

```
\begin{numcases}{A = }
\frac{r}{a} & r > a \tag{G} \\
\frac{a}{r} & r < a \tag{H}
\end{numcases}
```

utilizing the `numcases`environment from the `cases` package, and `\tag` from `amsmath`. However, the two don't seem to be compatible:

> `! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.`

Is there any alternatives that would do what I hope to accomplish?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the **empheq** package:

```
\usepackage{empheq}

\begin{empheq}[left={A=\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}
& \frac{r}{a} &&\qquad  r > a \tag{G} \\
& \frac{a}{r} &&\qquad  r < a \tag{H}
\end{empheq}
```

The syntax is a bit awkward, but the result seems good. You can define an environment for you personal use:

```
\newenvironment{tagcases}[1][]
  {\empheq[left={#1\empheqlbrace}]{alignat=2}}
  {\endempheq}
```

and the system before would become

```
\begin{tagcases}[A=]
& \frac{r}{a} &&\qquad  r > a \tag{G} \\
& \frac{a}{r} &&\qquad  r < a \tag{H}
\end{tagcases}
```