# ! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here

Tags: errors, amsmath

I want to use `\tag` in my LaTex file at https://www.sharelatex.com/.

For example, I want to do:

```
If $x \equiv x' \pmod{N}$ and $y \equiv y' \pmod{N}$, then: $xy \equiv x'y' \pmod{N}\tag{Substitution rule}$.
```

I look at a previous question on this website, [\numcases with \tag](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/35210/numcases-with-tag), and found the answer insufficient for my problem.

I still get the `! Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here.` error even though I am only importing the following:

```
\usepackage{textcomp,geometry,graphicx,hyperref,empheq}
```

I have two questions:

(1) Why does the `amsmath` package cause an error when `\tag` is used?
(2) How do I add customized tags to my equations without causing errors?

Thank you for any help you can provide on this!

EDIT:

This is a made-up example as requested:

```
Now solve for $E[X]$:\newline

    \hspace{30pt} $E[X] = 1 + E[X] - p \cdot E[X]$\newline

    \hspace{30pt} $0 = 1 - p \cdot E[X]\tag{"xyz"}$\newline

    \hspace{30pt} $p \cdot E[X] = 1\tag{"xyy"}$\newline

    \hspace{30pt} $E[X] = \frac{1}{p}\tag{"xzy"}$\newline\newline
```

[image]

Note the `\tag` parts were added in afterwards because they caused errors.

Then I want to say, based on "xyz" and "xyy", I can prove "abc".

Comment: I would guess it's because you're using it in inline math. 'Numbering' inline math seems weird to me. What exactly do you want to do? As it stands it looks like you may just as well use `\text` or write *Substitution rule* outside the math.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. This is just an example, but I have other non-inline equations I want to write (e.g. equations at different points of a proof). I want to give them special `\tag` names like "Substitution rule".

Comment: Can you then make a complete example with a displayed equation where it doesn't work?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Example added.

Comment: @user93172 Those are still _inline_ equations: the fact you are making them look like display doesn't make a difference.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're still using inline math. (La)TeX distinguishes between math that is supposed be written on a line of text, delimited by `$ ... $` or `\( ... \)`, and displayed math, which is placed on its own paragraph.

For a single unnumbered, displayed equation you can use `\[ ... \]`, for a numberered equation there is `\begin{equation} ... \end{equation}`. For sets of equations, or multiline equations, `amsmath` provides several environment, including `align` and `gather`, as well as the starred forms `align*` and `gather*` that are unnumbered.

Displayed equations are by default centered, to make them left-aligned add `fleqn` as an option to `amsmath` or the document class, e.g. `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`.

For more information about `amsmath`, read [the manual](http://texdoc.net/pkg/amsmath). For math typesetting in general, you could take a look at [Herbert Voss' Mathmode](http://texdoc.net/pkg/mathmode).

A demonstration with your example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
Now solve for $E[X]$:
\begin{gather}
E[X] = 1 + E[X] - p \cdot E[X] \\
0 = 1 - p \cdot E[X]\tag{"xyz"} \\
p \cdot E[X] = 1\tag{"xyy"} \\
E[X] = \frac{1}{p}\tag{"xzy"}
\end{gather}

Now solve for $E[X]$:
\begin{align}
E[X] &= 1 + E[X] - p \cdot E[X] \\
0 &= 1 - p \cdot E[X]\tag{"xyz"} \\
p \cdot E[X] &= 1\tag{"xyy"} \\
E[X] &= \frac{1}{p}\tag{"xzy"}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my confusion about inline vs. non-inline text! Thank you for the detailed rewriting of my code, which is an excellent example for me to work off of!

Answer (score 3):

These are still inline equations. You need to use

```
\[ formula \]
```

of

```
\begin{equation}
formula
\end{equation}
```

to make your formulas display style. Read about it [here](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/LaTeX%3aMath#Display_Math).

Comment: `\end{formula}` --> `\end{equation}`.

Comment: Thank you for clearing up my confusion about inline vs. non-inline text!

Comment: I recently got the "`\tag` not allowed here" error when I put a `\tag` inside `\[...\]`; but I was able to get the `\tag` to work inside `\begin{equation}...\end{equation}`, so it was no big deal. I was using a lot of packages; is this a known incompatibility?

Comment: @MSC In short, the two are not equivalent; `\[...\]` is equivalent to `\begin{displaymath}...\end{displaymath}` and neither create equation numbers. For an excellent explanation, look at [this very thorough answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/40531/23079).