# Does amsmath treat double dollars and `\[' `\]' delimiters differently?

Tags: errors, amsmath

I ran into what I think is an anomaly. I was trying to add tags to my displayed math equations in a document, and I ran into the error message

> Package amsmath Error: \tag not allowed here

which is the title of [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/132357/9446). That question was the first search engine hit to keywords *amsmath* and *tag*, which is why I am writing this.

Namely, unlike the asker of that question, my equation **was** in display math. Yet, I still get the same error message.

The answers to that related question were thus initially not helpful to me. Studying the examples as well as [the AMSmath documentation](ftp://ftp.ams.org/pub/tex/doc/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf) didn't enlighten me either. They did leave me wondering whether the design goal was that only equations in specified environments can be tagged. That sounded somewhat strange.

Copy/pasting examples from the answers came with a surprise. The appearance of this error message apparently depends on exactly how the equation was put into display mode. Try the following snippet:

```
\documentclass{report}[12pt]
\usepackage{latexsym,epsf,amsthm}
\usepackage[finnish]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{psfrag}
\def\theenumii{\arabic{enumii}}
\begin{document}
Firs test
\[
\frac32n^2+\frac12n\le 936.\tag{1}
\]
Second test
$$
\frac32n^2+\frac12n\le 936.\tag{1}
$$
\end{document}
```

You will see that the error message is generated by the version with double dollars, but **NOT** when we use the `\[` `\]` delimiters.

Thus I have solved my main problem. Posting this partly in case somebody else runs into the same problem (and linking it with the first hit). This does beg my title question

> Why aren't the various display math delimiters interchangable in AMSmath?

I learned TeX when plainTeX was all we had, so if I have to unlearn using double-dollars I won't be too happy. For example MathJax still uses double dollars, and as an active user at Math.SE (a moderator even) I frequently use them.

Why is there a difference here?

In case it matters, here is my configuration:

- laptop running on Windows 7
- WinEdt version 7.0
- MiKTeX version 2.9

Comment: You simply should ***never*** use `$$` in LaTeX. It's a pity that Math.SE doesn't accept `\[...\]`

Comment: Thanks for the piece of advice (and the link) @egreg. My learning curve is not what it once was, and unlearning is particularly taxing, but ... Sorry about the dup :-(

Comment: Adding the following comment: Apparently ou **can** use `\[...\]` in Math.SE if you [escape the backslash](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/26115/11619).